# How can I find the boundaries of the marginal PDF given the joint PDF and its boundaries? [with example]

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Random variables X and Y are distributed according to the joint PDF, $\ f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as

\begin{cases}
ax & \text{if $ 1 \leq x \leq 2$ and $\ 0 \leq y \leq x$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

The marginal PDF of $\ f_y$ of Y can be determined by integrating $\ f_{X,Y}$ with respect to X.

For this problem we are asked to determine $\ f_Y (y) $ on the  intervals $ 0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $\ 1 \leq y \leq 2 $. The choice of these intervals is mysterious to me. Equally mysterious to  me is the provided solution, that $\ f_Y (y) $ =

\begin{cases}
\int_1^2 \frac{3}{7}xdx  & \text{if $\ 0 \leq y \leq 1$} \\
\int_y^2 \frac{3}{7}xdx & \text{if $\ 1 \leq y \leq 2 $} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Can someone explain to me how the intervals for this marginal PDF are determined? I am at a loss and there isn't any supplementary material in my text that I can find.

Comment: So you look at the given inequality and focus on $x$. It says that $x \geq 1 \text{ and } x \leq 2 \text{ and } x \geq y$. So the upper bound is $2$, while the lower bound is $\max\{y, 1\}$, or in simple words it depends on the value of $y$. When $y \geq 1$, $x$ is bounded below by $y$; otherwise $x$ is simply bounded below by $1$ when $y \leq 1$.

Comment: Drawing a picture of the region with positive probability will be helpful to determine what you should be integrating. Once the picture is drawn, notice what bounds $x$ for different values of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider case when $ y < 1 $, then from $0 < y < x$, varible $x$ can be any value in its space, therefore first part of $f_y(Y)$ is given in that way.

In second case, region of integration can not be the same, because for $y > 1$ possible values for $x$ are $ y < x < 2$ again from $0 < y < x$.